# Django saving to database from form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form validation:

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        #Saving to database
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = AddForm() # An unbound form
return render(request, 'contact.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

And  I daont know how save the data to a database. For example I enter some data in template in field "name: cofee , category: food ". So how do I save it in database ?

Comment: if your AddForm is a ModelForm AddForm.save() should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the usual strategy is to implement a save method in your AddForm that would persist the data. 
It is a good practice to verify the validity of the data in the save method : that way you do not need to explicitely call the is_valid() method (accessing the errors attribute will trigger the cleaning and validation process implemented in the base django form class)

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        try:
            form.save()
        except:
            #handle exceptions
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = AddForm() 
        return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form,})

# save method to put in your form class
def save(self):
    if not self.errors:
        to_save = ObjModel(<name_of_the_object_model_field> = self.cleaned['<name_of_your_form_field_containing_the_data>'])
        to_save.save()
```

This is to described the generic django way of doing this summming up concepts you will find in the documentation. You can of course tune this to adapt to your needs.

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

To save the fields to the database, use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/), or use the new [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), which is even simpler:

In your `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from yourapp.models import SomeModel

class CreateSomeModel(CreateView):
    model = SomeModel
    template_name = 'some_template.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

In `some_template.html`:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In `home.html`:

```
<strong>This is the home page</strong>
```

In `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from yourapp.views import CreateSomeModel
from yourapp.views import Home

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^create/$', CreateSomeModel.as_view(), name='create'),
   url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),)
```